# Get small image url to ADT Liferay 7

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 7 as my content management system and freemarker as my template language.

How to get a small image url and also custom fields of my journal article?

I want to use those values in my ADT to render the articles in a custom way.

Comment: Please provide effort when you are asking a question.. And consider using an [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Read how to ask a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I got like this

First get the renderer from your current entry

<#assign renderer=curEntry.getAssetRenderer()>

Then get Journal Article from the renderer

<#assign article=renderer.getArticle()>

You can get all the custom fields from article variable

eg: for small image url

${article.getSmallImageURL()}

Comment: Thank you for your response but not works. Missing closed list </#list> value also missing another  </#if> value. Please review your code .

Comment: I edited the answer hope this helps you. If any further help required please post your code.